# Creating Azure self-signed sertificate with powershell Invoke-AddCertToKeyVault command

Tags: windows, powershell, azure

Recently, I tried to create self-signed certificate for Azure Service Factory accordingly with Microsoft's manual:
[Azure Docs: Secure a Service Fabric cluster, step 2.5, 02/05/2016](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-security/) 
But command `Invoke-AddCertToKeyVault` failed with the next error:

> Invoke-AddCertToKeyVault : The term 'Invoke-AddCertToKeyVault' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again.

I think that *Azure Powershell* successfully installed on my machine because I was able to login into my Azure account by running `Login-AzureRmAccount`. Also `$env:PSModulePath` says that Azure Modules path added to path variable (accordingly with the article: [Azure Docs: How to install and configure Azure PowerShell, 04/22/2016](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/)). Here they are:

> ...\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\;
>
> ...\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\;
>
> ...\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\Storage\;

Also, I have restarted my PC after installing *Azure PowerShell*.

It is possible that I have missed something, but I am stuck with it. How could it be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That commandlet is in the package that should be imported -

```
Import-Module "C:\Users\chackdan\Documents\GitHub\Service-Fabric\Scripts\ServiceFabricRPHelpers\ServiceFabricRPHelpers.psm1"
```

That is its [implementation](https://github.com/ChackDan/Service-Fabric/blob/master/Scripts/ServiceFabricRPHelpers/ServiceFabricRPHelpers.psm1), by the way, for a reference that it even exists :).  Try Import-Module and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot. The reason I have missed it - there was a reference to the step 2.5, so I switched to it without reading the information given before.